# How to manage vertical pod autoscaler for many deployments?

Tags: resources, prometheus, azure-aks, autoscaling

I'm running kubernetes on AKS with both staging and production clusters having only 2 vCPU/ 8GB per node. I'm constantly in a situation where new pods can't be scheduled due to insufficient CPU or memory.

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests      Limits
  --------           --------      ------
  cpu                1869m (98%)   25800m (1357%)
  memory             3561Mi (66%)  18484Mi (344%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
```

I understand that VPA can optimize the allocation per deployment. There are 4 deployments for kube-prometheus-stack (helm chart), 2 for open-telemetry-collector (one for the "operator" and one for the collector), and there are even more deployments for the rest of the monitoring stack (zipkin, elasticsearch, etc).

It seems unweildy to create individual VPA objects/manifests for every single deployment. That's a lot of yaml. Is this really the recommended practice? Is there a better way?

For a staging environment, some of the deployments have only 1 replica. VPA only updates resource requests for deployments that have at least 2 replicas. If I increase to 2, ironically that will consume (obviously) more requests, possibly more than the cluster can handle. VPA doesn't seem to be useful in this scenario.

Comment: I ended up just increasing the VM size of the nodes to accommodate the load. VPA is touted as the go-to solution for optimizing resource requests but that was not the case here. Creating 10 + VPA objects just wasn't feasible.

Comment: There's a tool `kubectl-vpa` that may help you with creation of multiple VPA objects: https://github.com/ninlil/kubectl-vpa#quick-start. Also, to allow the updater to update deployments w/ 1 replica, you can play with the option: `min-replicas Int Minimum number of replicas to perform update Default: 2` passed to the updater deployment via `args` to the image being run in a cluster.